# Jquery autocomplete line breaks not working

Tags: php, jquery, html, jquery-ui, cakephp

I am trying to return three lines of text to show in my autocomplete boxes but as you can see in the picture below it just displays the line break character but what I want is 3 lines of text.
[image: Screenshot of jquery autocomplete with no line breaks]

this is my Cakephp function i use to return the data.

```
public function partNumSearch()
    {

        if ($this->request->is('ajax')) 
        {
            $part = $this->request->query['term'];
            $resultArr = $this->Stocks
            ->find()
            ->where(
                ['Stocks.id LIKE' => ($part . '%')])
                ->orWhere(
                ['Stocks.alternative_part_number LIKE' => ($part . '%')])
                ->orWhere
                (['Stocks.description LIKE' => ($part . '%')]
            );



            $resultsArr = [];
            foreach ($resultArr as $result) 
            {       

                 $resultsArr[] = (strval($result['id']) . '\n' . $result['alternative_part_number'] . '\n'. $result['description'] );

            }

            $this->set(array(
            'id' => $resultsArr,
            '_serialize' => 'id'
            ));
        }
    }
```

This is my autocomplete script

```
jQuery('#part').autocomplete({ 
     delay: 0,
source:'<?php echo Router::url(array('controller' => 'Stocks', 'action' => 'partNumSearch')); ?>'
});
```

Comment: Change all your php `'\n'` to `"\n"` ...

Comment: But it may not show them depending on the html... you may be better off passing `<br>` instead (again, depends on the css/html of each element displayed).

Comment: better you doing like [this](https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#custom-data)

Comment: Change all your '\n' to '<br/>'.

Comment: @plonknimbuzz Thanks that worked!

Comment: glad to hear that mate

Answer (score 0):

use below autocomplete demo

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
      // #1 - Search configuration - to replace with your own
      var ALGOLIA_APPID = 'latency';
      var ALGOLIA_SEARCH_APIKEY = '6be0576ff61c053d5f9a3225e2a90f76';
      var ALGOLIA_INDEX_NAME = 'actors';
      var NB_RESULTS_DISPLAYED = 5;
      // #2- Algolia Client Initialization
      var algoliaClient = new algoliasearch(ALGOLIA_APPID, ALGOLIA_SEARCH_APIKEY); 
      var index = algoliaClient.initIndex(ALGOLIA_INDEX_NAME);
      var lastQuery = '';

      var array = [{'name':'Mehul'},{'name':'Hitesh'},{'name':'Parth'}];
      console.log(array);

      $('#MyText').textcomplete([
        {
          // #3 - Rgular experession used to trigger search
          match: /(^|\s)@(\w*(?:\s*\w*))$/,
          // #4 - Function called at every new keystroke
          search: function(query, callback) {
           
            lastQuery = query;
            index.search(lastQuery, { hitsPerPage: NB_RESULTS_DISPLAYED })
              .then(function searchSuccess(content) {
                if (content.query === lastQuery) {
                  console.log(content.hits);
                  callback(content.hits);
                }
              })
              .catch(function searchFailure(err) {
                console.error(err);
              });
              
          },
          // #5 - Template used to display each result obtained by the Algolia API
          template: function (hit) {
            // Returns the highlighted version of the name attribute
            return hit._highlightResult.name.value;
          },
          // #6 - Template used to display the selected result in the textarea
          replace: function (hit) {
            return ' @' + hit.name.trim() + ' ';
                      }
        }
      ]);
    });
```

```css
  #MyText {
  border:1px solid #ddd;
  padding: 10px;
  min-height: 40px;
  background: #fff;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 16px;
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.dropdown-menu {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1000;
  display: none;
  float: left;
  min-width: 160px;
  padding: 5px 0;
  margin: 2px 0 0;
  font-size: 14px;
  text-align: left;
  list-style: none;
  background-color: #fff;
  -webkit-background-clip: padding-box;
  background-clip: padding-box;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.15);
  border-radius: 4px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 6px 12px rgba(0,0,0,.175);
  box-shadow: 0 6px 12px rgba(0,0,0,.175);
}
.dropdown-menu > li > a {
  display: block;
  padding: 3px 20px;
  clear: both;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 1.42857143;
  color: #333;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.dropdown-menu {
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 16px;
  text-align: left;
  list-style: none;
}
.dropdown-menu .textcomplete-item.active a {
  background: #F0F0F0;
}

}
```

```html
<label for="MyText">Press @ and write</label>
<div id="MyText" contenteditable="true"></div>



<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.textcomplete/1.8.1/jquery.textcomplete.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/algoliasearch/3/algoliasearch.min.js"></script>
```